# Bluetooth device keeps disconnecting

Tags: terminal, bluetooth, serial-port

I want to connect the bluetooth on my laptop to a device nearby offering SPP, and then talk to the device using a terminal program. It works great from Windows, now I'm trying to recreate that from Linux. I have paired and trusted the device in Linux (using the Ubuntu GUI), and then (from my understanding of other posts) created a local tty device as follows:

```
root@ta-ms:~# sdptool add --channel=22 SP
root@ta-ms:~# rfcomm bind /dev/rfcomm1 BC:23:E0:82:5C:6a 22
```

Then start a terminal program on that device:

```
root@ta-ms:~# minicom -D /dev/rfcomm1
```

minicom will start and show a terminal window, but no data is moving either way when I type.

Can someone suggest what is wrong here?  Have I not setup the BT+SPP+RFCOMM/TTY correctly, or do I have some other problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the "sdptool" commands are no longer necessary, they are deprecated.  Most of the answers on SE still reference them, which is why many users are having problems.

Simply remove the sdptool command above but leave the rest, then everything will run reliably.  Since doing so I get a connection each time, works great.  Also, skip the BT channel number, so just use:

```
rfcomm bind /dev/rfcomm1 BC:23:E0:82:5C:6a
```